# History of Cohomology's formula $d^2=0$

Tags: homology-cohomology, math-history

I understand that the formula $d^2=0$ is an essential formula in all cohomology.  So I suddenly became curious about the history of the formula $d^2=0$.  Of course, this formula overlaps with Gauss's formula and Green's theorem, so it may have a similar history with these formulas, but I am curious about the specific origin and history of $d^2=0$.  So, if you know about this, I would appreciate it if you could provide an answer or recommend a related book.

Comment: I think this question is on topic, but you might want to consider posting it on our sister site about the history of science and mathematics hsm.stackexchange.com (cross-posting is frowned upon in the network, though, so you would probably have to choose one).

Comment: See Victor Katz on JSTOR. https://www.jstor.org/stable/41133758?saml_data=eyJzYW1sVG9rZW4iOiIwYmU5ZTBlMy1lYTc4LTRjY2UtOGFlNS05ZDc4ZmFlYTM3ZjMiLCJpbnN0aXR1dGlvbklkcyI6WyJjNWNiODgxNC02ZTQ3LTQ3ZjgtOTNhMS01MjUxYWQ2ZWYxODQiXX0.

Comment: @RolandF Thanks for your comment. But are there any other references that clearly state $d^2=0$ and talk about history in an easy to understand manner? If so, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: in my first terms in the 1960ties, I stumbled   into the middle of the fight between the young Bourbaki mathematicians with no teaching experience and the old fashioned specialists of tensor analysis and  classical linear algebra at Würzburg University. I bought a copy of Misner, Thorne, Wheeler, 'Gravitation' in the 1970ties, with their straight forward exposition of saying "d^2 =0 is equal to 'a boundary of a boundary is zero'  again and again" . Rather complete survey at Oberwolfach 
  - The History of the Mathematics of the 20th Century - https://publications.mfo.de/handle/mfo/2594